# What does 'reference..' mean in SQL syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax

```
from
[PMDB].[dbo].PROJECT P
inner join PROJWBS PW on P.proj_id = PW.proj_id
and PW.proj_node_flag = 'Y' and PW.wbs_short_name not like '%- B%'
and PW.status_code <> 'WS_Planned' and PW.status_code <> 'WS_Whatif'
inner join [PMDB].[dbo].TASKSUM TS on PW.proj_id = TS.proj_id and PW.wbs_id = TS.wbs_id
inner join reference..fiscal_year_qtr_month FYQM on isnull(TS.act_end_date,P.scd_end_date) > FYQM.fiscal_month_begin_datetime
and isnull(TS.act_end_date,P.scd_end_date) <= FYQM.fiscal_month_end_datetime
inner join reference..mfg_year_month_ww MYMW on isnull(TS.act_end_date,P.scd_end_date) > MYMW.mfg_ww_begin_datetime
a
```

I have tried the internet, but just don't understand what does the 'reference..' mean here. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reference` is a database name. In between the database name and the object name goes the schema.

So if you want to query from `sys.database_files` in `master`, you would say:

```
SELECT name FROM master.sys.database_files;
---- database ---^^^^^^
------------- schema ---^^^
----------------- object ---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can leave out the schema if you know the entity name is unambiguous. For catalog views/DMVs, you can't leave it out, but if you're using your default schema (usually dbo), you can leave out the explicit reference. [Not that that's a good idea](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Comment: But I don't see a database named 'reference'. Neither do I see the table 'fiscal_year_qtr_month ' in any other database on the instance.

Comment: Maybe you don't have rights to the table? At any rate, that is a question for your local dba or your boss.

Comment: I am trying to understand a someone else written report, to copy it on our migrated system. This helps and works. I found that I was missing the reference dbs, so I went out and learned how to copy that to our new instance. Thanks. Alls good now.

Answer (score 4):

```
reference..mfg_year_month_ww
```

is the short hand for

```
reference.dbo.mfg_year_month_ww
```

basically it means use default schema.

Comment: `reference` is the name of a *database*.

Comment: he asked what "reference.." meant, not "reference" .

Comment: @RandomUs1r  - +1.  You answered the question. "Q: What does reference..fiscal_year_qtr_month_ww mean?  A: It's shorthand.  The fully qualified name (in Microsoft-specific, T-SQL syntax) is "database.owner.table".

Comment: @paulsm4 if you're going to +1 people for one thing and -1 people for another, please get the terminology right at the very least. Unless you're working with SQL Server 2000, a table has a *schema* not an *owner*.

Comment: PS this isn't my down-vote so if you down-voted me for revenge because you made an assumption, well, that's not the way the site is supposed to work.

Comment: I happen to be 100% sure on this, and my answer actually answers the question in a clear and concise manner.  So the question with the most votes should be the superior answer, however it looks like you win the popularity contest with your terminology chucked/confusing answer (which goes way above the scope of the question into best practices (I happen to agree with)?), so I'll give you your vote back :)

Comment: Well to be quite honest your answer can be misleading. It is only true if my default schema is dbo.

Comment: @RandomUs1r: he's not winning a popularity contest. He's winning a correctness contest. The scope of the question is to explain what is a 4 part name - which Aaron's answer explained, while yours just skimmed.

Comment: I guess it can be if you fail to comprehend the implication of the 4th line of the answer.  In addition, dbo happens to be by far the most common schema prompting the code example.  Seriously though, I could care less, just trying to help OP understand their code.

Comment: "..just trying to help OP understand their code" - we're all here specifically for that. That's why the best answers get the most up-votes (and maybe a check mark). Yours is not the best, it's just good (hence no down-votes). So no, it's not a beauty contest ;).

Comment: @Marian ".." is Microsoft SQL specific syntax.  a 4 part name is universal.  I like for people to tell me why something works, not how, there's plenty of books out there on the how.  "Why it works" is because it's a. MS SQL b. shorthand for the default schema . There is nothing more to it.

Comment: If that is your intent then you should say `reference.your_default_schema.mfg_year_month_ww`. I specifically went out of my way to use something in `sys` to avoid that confusion. Just because you only have exposure to `dbo` and no other schemas does not make your answer magically correct.

Comment: Damn you got me... because i don't have 75k SOE points, I've never been exposed to another schema in my life.  Now let me help you... Pro-tip: don't recommend using sys databases for anything to newer users.  It's like you're reading every other word of my posts since I said "the most common schema" as opposed to "the only schema".  I'm above arguing with a random SOE member about how to answer questions, so good luck and have a nice day.

Comment: not taking anyone's side, both ans from Aaron and RandomUs1r, helped me understand my OP in their own terms. Thanks guys.

Answer (score -1):

That's T-SQL (Microsoft-specific) syntax indicating the table's name and owner.  The default owner is "dbo".  The default database is whichever one you're currenting "using".

Here are more details:

> http://examplesql.com/sqlserver-t-sql-tsql/dbo-dotdot-syntax/
>
> `SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2008.dbo.AWBuildVersion;`
>
> Truth be told, it isn’t rocket science.  ’..’ can be used as a
>   replacement for dbo when referring to the default schema in a tsql
>   query.  If you need to access the default database frequenty, the dbo
>   .. syntax shortcut can greatly increase your efficiency.

Comment: No, actually, it's not the owner, but rather the **database** where the object lives. The name is `reference..fiscal_year....` - the schema is not even mentioned in this name here.....

Comment: Actually no, I think you missed a `.`.

Comment: And the link offers *terrible* advice. How much efficiency do you gain by writing ambiguous code and saving three characters?